# sql, Union query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please I have 5 tables :

- cosmeticproducts(idp, productname,#idc)
- domesticproducts(iddp,description,reference,#idc)
- users(idu, u_name)
- commands(idc,#userid,date)
- market(idm, #userid, marketname, location)

I want to show all the records:

```
u_name|date      |marketname|location|productname|description|reference
ali   |12-06-2012|Aldi      |DE      |           | TABLE     |65416
sab   |12-06-2013|Aldi      |DE      | makeup    |           | 
sir   |12-06-2010|MG        |FR      |           | chairs    |416
```

Can we do this with union? But I think that for the union we should have the same attributes in the tables with the same number or in my case for example `cosmeticproducts` table contains less attributes then `domesticproducts`.

Please I need your help. How we can can do this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the tables described you don't have all the needed columns, that you want to show

Comment: could you show all your tables structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union tables that have different/missing columns by using nulls in the select.

For example:

```
SELECT a.Column1 AS 'Col1',
       a.Column2 AS 'Col2',
       null AS 'Col3',
       a.Column4 AS 'Col4'
FROM TableA AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.Column1 AS 'Col1',
       b.Column2 AS 'Col2',
       b.Column3 AS 'Col3',
       null  AS 'Col4'
FROM TableB AS b
```

I don't know if this will help with your specific question but should help you with unions.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I searched for :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Please take note of the example below that starts with **select u_name , cast(null as date) dt** you have to make sure the column `TYPES` are suitable for the data too. It can help if you use `CAST(NULL AS ...)` in the top query.

Answer (score 1):

*Can we do this with union?* No!

This is **way more** than `UNION` or `UNION ALL` can achieve. 
You are expecting data from different tables to align into single rows. That's NOT what UNION does.

Let's say we have the following information:

```
users
(idu, u_name)
  1     ali

commands
(idc,#userid,date)
  X      1    12-06-2012
```

So we create the following query:

```
      select u_name , cast(null as date) dt
      from users
UNION ALL -- union would produce the exact same result
      select null, date
      from commands
```

This is what you would get as a result:

```
U_NAME DT
ali    NULL
NULL   12-06-2012
```

2 rows!

If however you use `JOINS` you **MIGHT** get closer, this query:

```
SELECT u_name , c.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN commands c ON u.idu = c.#userid
```

would produce this result:

```
U_NAME DATE
ali    12-06-2012
```

**BUT** it is much more complex over the remaining tables because it isn't clear in all cases how the join, but also because some of the tables may have multiple rows for a join and all of a sudden you get many more rows than you expected.

Let's now say we also have this data:

```
market
(idm, #userid, marketname, location)
  Y1      1       ALDI         DE
  Y2      1       MG           FR
```

So we include this into our query using joins:

```
SELECT u_name , c.date, m.marketname, m.location
FROM users u
INNER JOIN commands c ON u.idu = c.#userid
INNER JOIN market m ON u.idu = m.#userid
```

**NOW** we get this result:

```
U_NAME DATE        MARKETNAME  LOCATION
ali    12-06-2012  ALDI         DE
ali    12-06-2012  MG           FR
```

Your requirement simply cannot be satisfied fully without supplying some sample data from each table and an "expected result" that relates to the data you provide.

Comment: Sorry, you haven't understood my question! I know what union does and I knew the differences between the joins and union! But Really thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: Then why ask if it can be done with UNION; **if you already know what UNION does?** Seriously, re-think your question, and prepare it with sample data and an expected result.

Comment: By my question, I wanted to know how we can use it exactly in my case.

Comment: The specific question was "Can we do this with union?" (this = the table shown) & the answer to that question is No. The reason being that no rows will be aligned by using union. But anyway I do hope you luck.